# It seems like years since it's been clear

Tags: british-english

1) It seems like years since it's been clear.
2) It seems like years since it's been here.

These are excerpts from the Beatles song, Here Comes The sun "

I often find it odd when I see since followed by the present participle.

Can someone tell me why the present perfect is preferred over the simple past in these examples?

Comment: "I often find it odd when I see since followed by the present participle". There are no present participles (-ing  participles) following *since* in your sentences. *Since* can be used with different tense forms of verbs. "When since is used for talking about time, the verb in the main clause of the sentence is usually in the present perfect or past perfect tense". "Sometimes the present simple or past simple is used in the main clause". Examples: It hasn’t rained since the end of July. It’s over twenty years since we last met.[http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/since]

Answer (score 2):

This is less about grammar and more about style.  Look at the prior line.

> ***It's been** a long cold lonely winter*
>
> *It feels like years since **it's been here***

This seems like rhetorical [Epanalepsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epanalepsis):

- the repetition of the initial word (or words) of a clause or sentence at the end of that same clause or sentence.

I'm guessing that *it* in the second line might refer back to "the sun," not to "the long cold lonely winter."  The grammatical reason to say "*It's been a long cold lonely winter*" is to allow for it to be still winter, as opposed to "***It was** a long cold lonely winter.*"

Even if George Harrison was saying "It was a long cold lonely winter, and it's been a long time since **winter's** been here," the line "**It's been** a long cold lonely winter" evokes a feeling of having just endured hardship, in contrast to the sun that "**is coming**."

Repeating "It's been" in the next line to say "*it's been clear*" is less a grammatical choice than a poetic one, opting to use a rhetorical technique to make the lines more powerful.  The lines simply wouldn't flow the way George Harrison wanted them to if he had written:

> ***It's been** a long cold lonely winter*
>
> *It feels like years since **it was** here.*